# TreeSet not iterating through entire set for remove - have overridden comparable

Tags: java, iterator, overriding, comparable, treeset

My treeset.remove() SOMETIMES works properly. But other times it does not iterate through all the elements searching for the match, so it does not remove the element I am searching for. Below is my override of treeset compareTo.

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
    String oid, sd;
    double p;
    int sz, time;
    public Entry(int time, String Order_id, String side, double price, int size){
    this.oid = Order_id;
    this.sd = side;
    this.p = price;
    this.sz = size;
    this.time = time;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry other) {
        if(this.oid.equals(other.oid))
                return 0;
        if (this.p > other.p)
            return 1;
        if (this.p < other.p)
            return -1;
        if(this.p == other.p){
            if(this.sd.equals(other.sd)){
                if(this.sd.equals("S"))
                    return ((this.sz >= other.sz) ? 1 : -1);
                if(this.sd.equals("B"))
                    return ((this.sz >= other.sz) ? -1 : 1);
                else{
                    if(other.sd.equals("S"))
                        return -1;
                    else
                        return 1;
                }

             }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In this case, it's iterating through about half the set and stopping one entry short of where it needs to remove, but all the values it's returning are 1.

Comment: Please indent the code.

Comment: Is that gonna make it work or just make it more readable?

Comment: Of course to not torture readers.

Comment: I removed a bunch of println statements prior to uploading it so that probably messed with the format.

Comment: OK. Would you like to fix it?

Comment: Just did. Thanks for pointing out the difficulty reading.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a very bad compareTo() implementation. You should not compare `this` or the `other` with constants like `S`. You have to compare them against each other.

I suggest you to read about usage of compareTo().

And maybe you can change your compareTo() like this:

```
public int compareTo(Entry other)
{
     if(this.oid.compareTo(other.oid) < 0)
         return -1;
     else if(this.oid.compareTo(other.oid) > 0)
         return 1;
     else
     {
        if (this.p > other.p)
            return 1;
        else if (this.p < other.p)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
      }
}
```

Just for inspiration, I don't mean to implement this way exactly. I don't know what you are trying to achieve either.

Comment: Your statement, "you should not compare with constants like `S`", is too general.  It may make sense in some cases.  Here, I think he's using the `"sd"` as some sort of code (an `enum` would be better), and it's definitely possible that if objects have this kind of code and two objects have equal codes, there may be different algorithms to determine which object is smaller, depending on the code.  Doing this would require using `equals` to check the code against a constant, or `switch` which would be better.  That seems to be what he's trying to do--incorrectly.

Comment: I really can't imagine a scenario that you would need a comparison against a constant in compareTo().

Comment: Suppose you have an object that represents a dog or a cat, with a string field `animalType` to indicate which.  It also has a size field.  You want to order them as follows: all dogs precede all cats, but for animals of the same type, you want smaller dogs to precede larger dogs, _but_ you want larger cats to precede smaller cats.  Why you would want this, I don't know, but this does define a total ordering.  The only way to implement this would be to have your `compareTo()` compare `animalType` to `"dog"` so that it knows how to compare the size.

Comment: There are only two contestants that sd can be, either S or B. This is still bad style? One goal I have right now is to make my code sexier, because it's got some uglier parts. I can definitely enumerate them. The comparator sorts based on price - and then if there is a tie deals with some other conditions. The (this.oid.equals(other.oid)) I recently added because remove didn't work without it, remove needs an explicit way to find the element. I just don't understand why it stops searching halfway through, when other times it iterates through the entire set.

Comment: The reason I'm using a TreeSet in the first place is to make sure the elements are sorted by price - the I want to access sell order S's for the cheapest price and buy order B's for most expensive price. So I have conditionals to place orders closer to their respective ends of the set to make for easier access. I have toyed with the idea of a BinaryTree but this is due tomorrow and I don't want to change the underlying data structure right now.

Comment: @AdamRebAlloy If the comparison function is wrong then a binary tree probably wouldn't work either.  Or any other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function is not a proper comparison function.  In order for the comparison function to work, it must follow the mathematical rules for a total ordering.  Basically, this means: x==x; x==y if and only if y==x, and x<y if and only if y>x; if x==y and y==z, then x==z; if x<y and y<z then x<z; similarly for >.

Your function fails on the last point, transitivity.  The function is strange-looking enough that it may fail on other points, too, but it's a bit difficult to analyze.  But to show that it's not transitive: Suppose object A has `oid=="x"`, `p==1.0`; object B has `oid=="y"`, `p==2.0`; object C has `oid=="x"`, `p==3.0`.  `A.compareTo(B)` will return 1, since the oid's are unequal and 1.0 < 2.0.  `B.compareTo(C)` will return 1, since the oid's are unequal and 2.0 < 3.0.  The transitivity rule means that, therefore, `A.compareTo(C)` must return 1.  But your function returns 0, since it always returns 0 if the oid's are equal.  So your function fails to follow the rules.  Since the algorithms for things like `TreeSet` rely on the comparison function being a valid comparison function, their behavior is unpredictable if you give it something that doesn't follow the rules.

**UPDATE:** Since I now have a better idea (from your comment) of what you're trying to achieve, I think I can point out what's going wrong.

The first part of the code seems to express the idea, "If the order ID is the same, the two objects are the same, but otherwise we'll sort by price".  You've already clarified that if the ID is the same, the price will be the same.  I might put in a check to make sure, because otherwise the `TreeSet` algorithm will return fishy results:

```
    if(this.oid.equals(other.oid)) {
        if (this.p != other.p) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Orders with same ID but different price");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This could catch bugs in the rest of your program.

OK, so we know the order ID's are different.  You want to sort by price.  If multiple entries have the same price (and are all different orders), then: some items will have sd=S and some will have sd=B.  It looks like you want to sort the S's in ascending order by size, and the B's in descending order by size.  But where do the S's and B's themselves go?

You'll need to decide: either you want the S's first and then the B's, or you want the B's first and then the S's.  (If you want something more complex than that, you'll have to figure it out yourself.)  The way you've coded it, if one object is an S and the other is a B (when the prices are equal), you always return 1.  So if two objects X and Y have the same price, but different sd fields, `X.compareTo(Y)` returns 1, and `Y.compareTo(X)` returns 1.  That means that X must come after Y and Y must come after X.  That doesn't work.

So the first thing you'll need to add is more logic if `this.sd.equals(other.sd.equals)` is false.  You'll either need `String.compareTo()` or some other mechanism to ensure that either the B always comes before the S, or the S always comes before the B, whichever you choose.  This is probably the big error that's causing the problem.

Upon reading this more closely, it appears that you might have actually tried to do this, with the code

```
            else{
                if(other.sd.equals("S"))
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 1;
```

which would accomplish the very thing you need to accomplish, if it were in the right place.  Unfortunately, it's attached to the wrong `if`.  The `else` part needs to happen if the sd's are not equal.  You need to fix the curly braces.  And, to avoid accidents like this, it's helpful to always use curly braces in an `if` statement, even if the body of the `if` is only one statement.  So I guess the answer to your question is: yes, the problem is due to poor syntax on your part.

The next mistake is here:

```
return ((this.sz >= other.sz) ? 1 : -1);
```

A `compareTo()` function is supposed to return a positive integer if the left argument is greater, a negative integer if the left argument is less, and 0 if they're equal.  You never return 0 here, though.  This means if you have to entries with different order ID's, but same price, sd, and size, you will again reach a situation where `X.compareTo(Y)` is 1 and `Y.compareTo(X)` is also 1, which is not supposed to happen.  This may not be causing your errors if all the sizes are different.  But it's still poor practice to depend on this.  You need to make sure to check the sizes for equality and return 0 if they're equal.  There's an `Integer.compareTo(int1, int2)` function that will be helpful here, so that you don't have to use a repeated `?:` operator.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. In this case all oid's are unique. What I get is an input that contains  and order id oid = (a unique number), type sd ("S" for sell or "B" for buy), a price p = #.#, and a size sz = a number. So I'm not going to get the same oid with data that differs elsewhere. The comparator's main goal is to list Entries by price, with a few other conditions in case of a tie. You think the fact that remove does not iterate through the entire set is due to poor syntax on my part?